# XHR failed loading: POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

so I am trying to post with ajax, and it just wont go through.

here is my javascript

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: "",
      url: 'some url',
      data: order,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function() {
        Materialize.toast('Order added successfully', 4000, 'android-success');
        console.log('order posted');

      },


      error: function() {
        Materialize.toast('Something went wrong', 4000, 'android-error');
      }

    }); // $.ajax post
```

I am not getting an error nor am I getting a success from ajax. But I am getting a chrome console error listed above `XHR failed loading: POST`

I have tried setting content type and data type to no avail. My guess, the problem is in the object format or something of that sort.

Probably useful information -- 
this is a basic outline of my code.

1. I have a button with on click event
2. in that function i have if else statement
3. if the input fields are blank event.preventdefault() the button click
4. else ajax post

This is the info under the failed log

```
send    @   jquery-3.1.0.js:9392

ajax    @   jquery-3.1.0.js:8999

(anonymous function)    @   ajax.js:20

mightThrow  @   jquery-3.1.0.js:3508

process @   jquery-3.1.0.js:3576
```

Any help on this matter really appreciated.

Comment: `just wont go through` from `where` to `where`?

Comment: You need to provide a URL for the ajax request. `url: 'some url',` I don't think this is not what you want to do.

Comment: I am dealing with cross origin, but back end took care of that, since I can GET with no problem

Comment: This is a dummy URL, The URL I've got works great on GET, even thou it is cross-origin. With unreachable, or miss-spelled URL I would have gotten an error from jquery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it to work. The problem was with the page reloading. So before the post request could go through the web page would reload which resulted in no error but just a failed log. Ugh, such a rookie mistake.

Comment: Could you please explain more detail about the issue which you found?

Comment: the button that fired up the AJAX request also reloaded the page interrupting my AJAX inner workings.

Comment: I am running into this problem. Could you please explain what you did to fix it?

Comment: My issue was the button that triggered the ajax post caused the webpage to reload before I could get a result, therefore, there was no details on the error. Check your `href` attribute make sure it doesn't reload the page. Just to be safe put this `#0` for the attribute value. 

So something like this: `<a href="#0" id="ajaxCall">AJAX</a>`
This fixed my issue.

Comment: You are a genius and a lifesaver. I never suspected this will be the cause. Front-end development is weird.

Answer (score 9):

When the window is loaded add an event listener for the form and prevent the default action.

```
 <script>
 window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    //not jquery!
    // Access the form element...
    var form = document.getElementById("myFormId");
    
    // ...and take over its submit event.
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission and reloading the page.

        //your code to validate or do what you need with the form.
    });
});
</script>
```