# Ajax request in cordova not working

Tags: php, ajax, cordova

I am using ajax request to a php script in order to registrate a new user, it works and saves it in the database, but returns as error and not as success.

This is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/webAPI/register.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,                        
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == 1)
                            alert("success");

                        else(data == 0 ) 
                            alert("error");

                    },
                    error: function (){
                           alert("An Error Ocurred");
                     }


                });
```

and this is my php script:

```
if($_POST)
{
    $user_name      = $_POST['username'];
    $user_password  = $_POST['password'];
    $joining_date   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    //password_hash see : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
    $password   = password_hash( $user_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 11));


        //if($count==0){
            $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password,joiningdate) VALUES(:uname,:pass,:jdate)");
            $stmt->bindParam(":uname",$user_name);
            $stmt->bindParam(":pass",$user_password);
            $stmt->bindParam(":jdate",$joining_date);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                echo 1;

            }
            else
            {
                echo 0;

            }
```

}

Comment: What alert do you get ? "error" or "an error occurred" ?

Comment: Do a json stringify of the data object in your Ajax function

Comment: I am getting the an error occurred

Comment: Ok, see my answer, look at the `error` function, it must tell you more about the error.

Comment: The problem was, it must contain datatype: 'json' in the ajax request. That's all!

Answer (score 1):

replace else(data == 0 ) with else

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost/webAPI/register.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        crossDomain: true,
                        cache: false,                        
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data == 1)
                                alert("success");

                            else
                                alert("error");

                        },
                        error: function (){
                               alert("An Error Ocurred");
                         }




  });
```

and in PHP code

```
if($stmt->execute())
            {
                exit(1);

            }
            else
            {
                exit(0);

            }
```

Comment: I tried and it still giving me alert An error ocurred, strange because the username and password are being saved on the database, also I have tried in php this echo json_encode("success");

Comment: This does not help.  The if condition is never executed

Comment: Try by exiting your php code may be it is not returning code

Comment: The only problem, was that it must contain the datatype property in the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the PHP response in JSON in order to check the result from JS.

The PHP response :

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    die(json_encode(['return' => true]));
} else {
    die(json_encode(['return' => false]));
}
```

And from JS, just check the `return` flag :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/webAPI/register.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'JSON', // tell JS that the PHP response is json formated
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,                        
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.return) { // check if return is true
            alert("success");
        } else { // if return is false
            alert("error");
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); // this will tell you more in case of unsuccessful request
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

#### EDIT :

Look at the Ajax `error` attribute function. It must tell you more about the error.

#### RE-EDIT :

The `dataString` you send to PHP must be a JSON object. So from your comment, it must look like :

```
var dataString = {
    username: $("#username").val(),
    password: $("#password").val()
};
```

Comment: It still throwing alert("Still Error!")

Comment: Yes but you will see more information in the console. To see the console, in firefox, use the shortcut CTRL + SHIFT + K.

Comment: @Mrfrog, so, what do you see in the console ? What error ?

Comment: this is what I got in the console: XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//localhost/DentistClinicAPI/register.php".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374549/xhr-failed-loading-post @Mrfrog try this

Comment: @Mrfrog Good, we have now more information. May you add in your question an example of `dataString` content, please ?

Comment: @JazZ     var user = $("#username").val();
                var pwd = $("#password").val();
                var dataString = "username=" + user + "&password=" + pwd;
Just a remainder it still saving to the database.

Comment: @Mrfrog ok, see the RE-EDIT part. Please let me know if you face a new error. Good luck. ; )

Comment: Well, I have tried many ways, I guess there might be some policies that are not well implemented in some meta tags maybe.

Comment: Maybe take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464921/cross-domain-xhr-failing

Answer (score 0):

The only problem was the missing datatype property in the ajax request.